# Can Cref also provide the title of the tcolorbox?

Tags: tcolorbox, cleveref

For instance, with

```
 \begin{mybluebox}[label={myreference}]{My title}
 This is an example. 
 \end{mybluebox}
```

From `(tcolorbox Manual, page 99)`

I would like to get `Bluebox 5.1 My title` instead of just `Bluebox 5.1` which is what `\Cref{myreference}` gives.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One solution would be to add the title as part of the number using the `number freestyle` option:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[
  auto counter,
  number within=section,
  number freestyle={\noexpand\thesection.\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter}~\noexpand\mytitle},
  crefname={bluebox}{blueboxes}]%
{mybluebox}[2][]{
  colback=blue!5!white,
  colframe=blue!75!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  code={\def\mytitle{#2}},
  title=Bluebox \thetcbcounter,%
  #1}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\begin{mybluebox}[label={myreference}]{My title}
This is an example.
\end{mybluebox}

\Cref{myreference}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is only now that I tried it and, of course, it works. The only thing is that I do not know how to control the color of `My Title` in the reference and, since I am using `hyperref`, `My Title` appears with the `linkcolor`. How could I have `My Title` the same color as `Bluebox` namely black?

Comment: @schremmer I do not think that is possible since the whole `\Cref{myreference}` gets colored with `linkcolor`...

Comment: I thought you might perform a miracle but, by now, I got used to it and I even think that's the way it _ought_ to be. So it's just as well. Thanks for a GREAT package. Made my life miserable for a while because now I had to redo properly all the stuff I had done ad hoc. But it was very much worth it.

Comment: @schremmer You may be interested in question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315809/referencing-named-tcbtheorems and its answers.