# Referencing named tcbtheorems

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, tcolorbox, cleveref, thmtools

My objective is exactly the same as in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109843/cleveref-and-named-theorems), however, I would like to achieve this same effect with `\newtcbtheorem` from the `tcolorbox` package.  For example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\newtcbtheorem{thm}{Theorem}{}{thm}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}{My awesome theorem}{awesome}
Isn't this theorem so awesome?
\end{thm}

This is a reference to \nameref{thm:awesome}.

\end{document}
```

should print "This is a reference to My awesome theorem.".

Unfortunately, the answer to the linked question no longer works if I use `\newtcbtheorem` instead of `\newtheorem`.  Is there a way to modify that answer to work in this case?

(Note that wrapping the `\begin{thm}\end{thm}` created by a `\newtheorem` call in a `\tcbenvironment` is not an option for reasons not mentioned here.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that `\@currentlabelname` is not defined which is written to the `.aux` by `nameref`'s version of `\label`.

The easiest way to solve this is either a patch or slight redefinition, setting `\@currentlabelname` with `{##2}`, which expands later on to contain the theorem name.  (A patch would also do!)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\makeatletter


\renewcommand{\new@tcbtheorem}[5][]{%
  \@@newtcolorbox[auto counter,#1]{#2}[3][]{#4,%
    title={\tcb@theo@title{#3}{\thetcbcounter}{##2}},%
    list entry={\protect\numberline{\thetcbcounter}##2},%
    code={\gdef\@currentlabelname{##2}\tcb@theo@label{#5}{##3}},%
    ##1}%
  \@@newtcolorbox[#1,no counter,list inside=]{#2*}[2][]{#4,%
    title={\tcb@theo@title{#3}{\@empty}{##2}},%
    ##1}%
}
\makeatother




\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtcbtheorem{thm}{Theorem}{}{thm}


\begin{document}

This is a reference to \nameref{thm:awesome} and \ref{thm:awesome}%

\clearpage
\begin{thm}{My awesome theorem}{awesome}
Isn't this theorem so awesome?
\end{thm}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome.  This seems to work.  What is the `\usepackage{xpatch}` used for though (I removed this and it still seemed to work).

Comment: @JonathanGleason: A remainder of a previous version -- it's not used here. Basically, it can be used for injecting code into other code with redefinition, but it would not be really shorter than the `\renewcommand`.

Comment: I wonder if I should add `\@currentlabelname` or `\NR@gettitle` as standard for `\new@tcbtheorem`. It wouldn't hurt much to have it there, if `nameref` is not used. Making it an selectable option would be a little bit ugly...

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: I would have written to you about this anyway. No, I think an option is not useful here.

Answer (score 4):

Credits go to Christian Hupfer for solving the requests in his answer.

I can add a shorter way to implement Christians solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\makeatletter
 \newtcbtheorem{thm}{Theorem}{code={\edef\@currentlabelname{#2}}}{thm}
%\newtcbtheorem{thm}{Theorem}{code={\NR@gettitle{#2}}}{thm}  % alternatively, if nameref is loaded
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is a reference to \nameref{thm:awesome} and \ref{thm:awesome}%

\clearpage
\begin{thm}{My awesome test theorem}{awesome}
Isn't this theorem so awesome?
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hm, I thought I had tried the `code=...` option too. It failed, perhaps there's was another error in my trials!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Possibly the `#2/##2` trap? ;-)

Comment: Possibly, yes ;-) I can't remember and don't have the older code at hand.