# "number freestyle" causes an overlay in the list of tcolorboxes

Tags: table-of-contents, tcolorbox, cleveref

This is a follow up on [Can Cref also provide the title of the tcolorbox?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312810/can-cref-also-provide-the-title-of-the-tcolorbox) because the Answer which "adds the title as part of the number using the `number freestyle` option" seems to create in the `list of tcolorboxes`

- an overlay,
- a double numbering.

namely

[image]

Here is the code:

```
 \documentclass{book}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
        \tcbuselibrary{skins,}  

\newcounter{thm}%[chapter] 
\newtcolorbox%
[%
use counter= thm,
number within=chapter,
number freestyle={\noexpand\thechapter.\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter}~\noexpand\mytitle},%
list inside= thm,%creates the list under tcblistof
crefname={Theorem}{Theorems},
Crefname={Theorem}{Theorems},
]%
{heorem}%
[2][]%
{%
detach title,%
before upper={\tcbtitle\quad},%
arc=0.2mm,%
colback=green!5,%
colframe=green!35!black,%
fonttitle=\bfseries,%
coltitle=black,%
code={\def\mytitle{#2}},%
title=THEOREM \thetcbcounter,%
#1%
}%

\begin{document}
\chapter{ONE}
\section{one}
\begin{heorem}[label={thm:1-1}]{Continuity}\hspace{-4mm}
Necessary for a good storyline.
\end{heorem}


See \cref{thm:1-1}

\tcblistof[\chapter]{thm}{List of Theorems}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The main reason is that `tcolorbox` adds the number and box title already to the List of Theorems, your numbering style adds the number again with some extra text. This won't work this way!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I suppose so but this was Sturm's answer in the question mentioned above. It works very well with `\cref` but how do I get it to work in the list too? Are you telling me that I can't have my cake and eat it too?

Comment: See the answer please -- I am away for some hours and can't update it however in short

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `list entry` option to override the default `title=` entry to the `List of...`

```
 \documentclass{book}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,}  

\newcounter{thm}%[chapter] 
\newtcolorbox%
[%
use counter= thm,
number within=chapter,
number freestyle={\noexpand\thechapter.\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter}~\noexpand\mytitle},
list inside= thm,%creates the list under tcblistof
list type=heorem,
crefname={Theorem}{Theorems},
Crefname={Theorem}{Theorems},
]%
{heorem}%
[2][]%
{%
detach title,%
before upper={\tcbtitle\quad},%
arc=0.2mm,%
colback=green!5,%
colframe=green!35!black,%
fonttitle=\bfseries,%
coltitle=black,%
code={\gdef\mytitle{#2}},
title={THEOREM \thetcbcounter},%
list entry={THEOREM~\thetcbcounter},
#1%
}%

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\l@heorem{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}} % For customization of the spacings
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{ONE}
\section{one}
\begin{heorem}[label={thm:1-1}]{Continuity}\hspace{-4mm}
Necessary for a good storyline.
\end{heorem}


See \cref{thm:1-1}

\tcblistof[\chapter]{thm}{List of Theorems}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there no way I could have the whole cake? Namely `Theorem 1.1 Continuity` both for `\cref` and in the `list`?

Comment: I think it is possible but I can't do much right now

Comment: @schremmer: See the update please

Comment: Exactly what the doctor ordered. (At least until I find some other problem.) So, I was right to push!!!! :-))

Comment: It seems to work in the magnum opus.

Comment: @schremmer: That's fine. Happy TeXing!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution. We need to redefine two commands

```
{
\renewcommand*\numberline[1]{}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\l@tcolorbox}{\@dottedtocline{-1}{0pt}{-2.3em}}
\tcblistof[\chapter]{thm}{List of Theorems}
}
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
        \tcbuselibrary{skins,}  

\newcounter{thm}%[chapter] 
\newtcolorbox%
[%
use counter= thm,
number within=chapter,
number freestyle={\noexpand\thechapter.\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter}~\noexpand\mytitle},%
list inside= thm,%creates the list under tcblistof
crefname={Theorem}{Theorems},
Crefname={Theorem}{Theorems},
]%
{heorem}%
[2][]%
{%
detach title,%
before upper={\tcbtitle\quad},%
arc=0.2mm,%
colback=green!5,%
colframe=green!35!black,%
fonttitle=\bfseries,%
coltitle=black,%
code={\def\mytitle{#2}},%
title=THEOREM \thetcbcounter,%
#1%
}%

\begin{document}
\chapter{ONE}
\section{one}
\begin{heorem}[label={thm:1-1}]{Continuity}\hspace{-4mm}
Necessary for a good storyline.
\end{heorem}


See \cref{thm:1-1}

{
\renewcommand*\numberline[1]{}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\l@tcolorbox}{\@dottedtocline{-1}{0pt}{-2.3em}}
\tcblistof[\chapter]{thm}{List of Theorems}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is also what I wanted except that I couldn't see how to get lowercases in the list while I could in Hupfer's. So, I accepted Hupfer's but voted up both. Thanks to you too.